# noUiSlider or jQuery Slider - Force user to slide the handle only

Tags: jquery-ui, slider, nouislider

I have not found a configuration option in the docs for either widget, but is there a way to implement the [noUiSlider](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/) or [jQuery UI Slider](https://jqueryui.com/slider/) to provide this functionality in a localized way (localized = allow default functionality where needed in other sections of the DOM):

- User must click and drag the handle to set a value
- User cannot click on the bar to set the value -> value not set to where user clicked

This is for a business requirement, and while I don't mind learning how to re-write a slider from scratch in vanilla JS, it is quite nice to use well-supported widgets. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in noUiSlider by setting `behaviour: 'none'`. See [the documentation](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/behaviour-option/#section-examples) for more info.

Comment: This seems to work for me, thanks. Do you know if there's a similar option in jQuery UI Slider?